# Prepare Teams App Dependencies fails behind proxy

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2022, teams-toolkit

I create a new Teams application in Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.4). When I try the "Prepare Teams App Dependencies", I get a failure from AppStudioPlugin with the message "API call to Developer Portal failed: Error, connect EACCES 52.113.194.132:443, API name: create-app, ..."
I am behind a proxy, and I see a drop in the firewall logs to 52.113.194.132:443, so it's not going to the proxy.

When I open a browser on that machine, I can go to the developer portal (https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/) without a problem, so the proxy does allow this.

When I open port 443 in the firewall, everything works.

My question is: How do I get it to work via the proxy ?

I did already try to add the proxy to the visual studio config, but also that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

17.4 VS Teams Toolkit uses a language server to handle data between VS and Teams Dev portal. You can try to add this language server to your proxy and test it.

```
Language server location: ~\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\{VS_version}\extensions\Microsoft\teams toolkit\{Teams_toolkit_version}\server.exe
```